# Add runtime variables to UI elements which inherit from UIControl/NSControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, storyboard

I've noticed that there's an option to bind runtime attribute for NSButton or any user UI element as shown in the example below. But how can I access this attribute from code for get/set operations ?

[image]

I've read that I cannot initialize attribute that isn't part of the class, but if I'll define category for NSControl which is inherited by NSButton class with runtime setter and getter to xxx, would it be possible :

```
@implementation NSControl (withXXX)
@dynamic xxx;

- (void)setXxx:(id)object {    
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(xxx), object, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (id)xxx {    
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(xxx));
}
```

Comment: Just add a ```@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString * xxx;``` to your class.

Comment: but if I want that properly to be in every ui item that inherit from NSControl and not just NSButton ? Since I cannot add properties to category , I was thinking about runtime solution

Comment: All the classes that share that property should inherit from the same VC if possible, otherwise you need to maybe look at the design. Use that property e.g. for a manual presenter class. Then the page is stored as the property and it is easy to make it work for all manual pages. If it gets too complex, or, as in your case, too general, then maybe you can not use that property to make it work.